# Finding items in an image which have the same intensity

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

How can I find all the points (or the region) in an image which has 3-dimensions in which the first two dimensions show the resolution and the 3rd one shows the density? I can use Matlab or Python. I wonder if there is a native function for finding those points that is least computationally expensive.
UPDATE:
Imagine I have the following:

```
A= [1,2,3; 4,6,6; 7,6,6]
A =

     1     2     3
     4     6     6
     7     6     6

>> B=[7,8,9; 10,11,11; 1, 11,11]

B =

     7     8     9
    10    11    11
     1    11    11

>> C=[0,1,2; 3, 7, 7; 5,7,7]

C =

     0     1     2
     3     7     7
     5     7     7
```

How can I find the lower square in which all the values of A equal the same all the values of B and all the values of C? If this is too much how can I find the lower square in A wherein all the values in A are equal?
*The shown values are the intensity of the image.

UPDATE: tries the provided answer and got this error:

```
>> c=conv2(M,T, 'full');
Warning: CONV2 on values of class UINT8 is obsolete.
         Use CONV2(DOUBLE(A),DOUBLE(B)) or CONV2(SINGLE(A),SINGLE(B)) instead. 
> In uint8/conv2 (line 10) 
Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d real'.

Error in uint8/conv2 (line 17)
y = conv2(varargin{:});
```

*Also tried `convn` and it took forever so I just stopped it!
Basically how to do this for a 2D array as described above?

Comment: I don't understand what "the first two dimensions show the resolution and the 3rd one shows the density" means, but you're probably looking for a histogram function. Can you give us a small example of what your image looks like?

Comment: @beaker I added some update. Please let me know if it is more clear or if you might need further details?

Comment: @MonaJalal What is your expected output?

Comment: `datenum` has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
A = [1,2,3; 4,6,6; 7,6,6];
B = [7,8,9; 10,11,11; 1, 11,11];
C = [0,1,2; 3, 7, 7; 5,7,7];
%create a 3D array
D = cat(3,A,B,C)
%reshape the 3D array to 2D 
%its columns represent the third dimension
%and its rows represent resolution
E = reshape(D,[],size(D,3));
%third output of the unique function applied row-wise  to the data
%represents the label of each pixel a [m*n, 1] vector created
[~,~,F] = unique(E,'rows');
%reshape the vector to a [m, n] matrix of labels
result = reshape(F, size(D,1), size(D,2));
```

You can reshape the 3D matrix to a 2D matrix (`E`) that its columns represent the third dimension and its rows represent resolution.

Then using `unique` function you can label the image.

We have a 3D matrix:

```
A =
     1     2     3
     4     6     6
     7     6     6
B =
     7     8     9
    10    11    11
     1    11    11
C =
     0     1     2
     3     7     7
     5     7     7
```

When we reshape the 3D matrix to a 2D matrix `E` we get:

```
E =

    1    7    0
    4   10    3
    7    1    5
    2    8    1
    6   11    7
    6   11    7
    3    9    2
    6   11    7
    6   11    7
```

So we need to classify the rows base on their values.

Unique function is capable of extracting unique rows and assign the same label to rows that are equal to each other.

Here varible `F` capture third output of the unique function that is label of each row.

```
F =

   1
   4
   6
   2
   5
   5
   3
   5
   5
```

that should be reshaped to 2D

result =

```
1   2   3
4   5   5
6   5   5
```

so each region has different label.

If you want to segment distinct regions(based on both their values and their spatial positions) you need to do labeling the image in a loop

```
numcolors = max(F);
N = 0;
segment = zeros(size(result));
for c = 1 : numcolors
    [label,n] = bwlabel(result==c);
    segment = segment +label + logical(label)*N;
    N = N + n;
end
```

So here you need to mark disconnected  regions that have the same values  with different labels. since MATLAB doesn't have functions for gray segmentation You can use `bwlabel` function multiple times to do segmentation and add result of the previous iteration to result of current iteration. `segment` variable contains the segmentd image.

*Note: this result obtained from GNU Octave that its labeling is different from MATLAB. if You use `unique(E,'rows','last');` result of MATLAB and Octave will be the same.

Comment: sounds terrific. just checking, my original arrays are 3D basically they are like m*n*q in which q is the intensity and m*n are the dimension. Should I change the whole code accordingly or only the last line result=reshape(F, [m,n]);

Comment: also is there any chance you could provide some comments for your code or further explanation? I find some of the lines hard to follow coming from a Python/Java background :)

Comment: if possible please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104568/why-does-gray-threshold-becomes-zero

Comment: Yes you can use `result=reshape(F, [m,n]);` . I updated the answer and added some explanations.

Comment: it all works great and correct expect I don't know why it output of greythresh as zero?? :O `>> [~,~,F]=unique(E,'rows', 'last');
>> result = reshape(F, size(D,1), size(D,2));
>> image(result)
>> graythresh(result)

ans =

     0`

Comment: On a sidenote, could more distinct colors be used for labeling? Thanks for suggestions and guidance

Comment: The number of labels is equal to distinct(unique) rows so here we have 6 distinct rows

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks a lot for help and guidance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135214/discussion-between-mona-jalal-and-rahnema1).

Comment: please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124823/how-can-i-only-select-the-segments-that-are-adjacent-to-a-given-segment I was not sure if you saw my question in the chat or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pair of horizontal and vertical 1D filters such that the horizontal filter has a kernel of `[1 -1]` while the vertical filter has a kernel of `[1; -1]`.  The effect of this is that it takes both horizontal and vertical pairwise distances for each element in each dimension separately. You can then perform image filtering or convolution using these two kernels ensuring that you replicate the borders.  To be able to find uniform regions, by checking which regions in both results map to 0 between them both, this gives you areas where areas that are uniform over all channels independently.

To do this, you would first take the **opposite** of both filtering results so that uniform regions that would become 0 are now 1 and vice-versa.   that you perform the `logical` AND operation on both of these together and then ensure that for each pixel temporally, all of the values are `true`.  This would mean that for a spatial location in this image, all values experience the same uniformity as you expect.

In MATLAB, assuming you have the Image Processing Toolbox, use [`imfilter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) to filter the images, then use [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) in MATLAB to look temporally after the two filtering results, and then use [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to find the coordinates of the regions you seek.  So do something like this:

```
%# Reproducing your data
A = [1,2,3; 4,6,6; 7,6,6];
B = [7,8,9; 10,11,11; 1, 11,11];
C = [0,1,2; 3, 7, 7; 5,7,7];

%# Create a 3D matrix to allow for efficient filtering
D = cat(3, A, B, C);

%# Filter using the kernels
ker = [1 -1];
ker2 = ker.'; %#
out = imfilter(D, ker, 'replicate');
out2 = imfilter(D, ker2, 'replicate');

%# Find uniform regions
regions = all(~out & ~out2, 3);

%# Determine the locations of the uniform areas
R = regionprops(regions, 'BoundingBox');

%# Round to ensure pixel accuracy and reshape into a matrix
coords = round(reshape([R.BoundingBox], 4, [])).';
```

---

`coords` would be a `N x 4` matrix with each row telling the upper-left coordinates of the bounding box origin as well as the width and height of the bounding box.  The first and second elements in a row are the column and row coordinate while the third and fourth elements are the width and height of the bounding box.

The regions we have detected can be found in the `regions` variable.  Both of these show:

```
>> regions

regions =

  3×3 logical array

   0   0   0
   0   1   1
   0   1   1

>> coords

coords =

     2     2     2     2
```

This tells us that we have localised the region of "uniformity" to be the bottom right corner while the coordinates of the top-left corner of the bounding box are row 2, column 2 with a width and height of 2 and 2 respectively.

Comment: your answer is great but is it generalizable to the situations when the area is not rectangular? It could be basically any sort of region. I provided the example above just to illustrate it. I'll get back to you soon :)

Comment: @MonaJalal You can only specify matrices that are square or rectangular.  Non-uniform matrices are not supported in MATLAB.  However, this answer should apply to any sized matrix provided that it can fit in memory.

Comment: I was looking for ways to show each element of D as a triplet, but didn't find something useful. Are you trying to serve the same purpose or is it the same as <a,b,c> triplets?

Comment: What is the expected output? That is missing in your question and Suever asked this a few moments ago.

Comment: sorry I was confusing, matrices (A, B, C) are rectangular but the region in which all the values of triplets of <a,b,c> is unique definitely is not necessarily rectangular. Does this makes sense?

Comment: tbh I am confused, considering the fact there could be more than one region with various intensities, definitely I don't think showing 0 and 1 would work out. However I think gearing towards location of items in a 2D matrix would make more sense in this case. What are your thoughts?

Comment: What "locations" are you seeking?  Do you want the 3D coordinates of `D` that satisfy this uniformity you are seeking?  Consider myself as someone that has absolutely no idea about your field or what you are after.  Explain what you want to achieve to me as if I was someone in kindergarten.

Answer (score 0):

check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html

2D correlation basically "slides" the two images across each other, and adds up the dot product of the overlap.

more reading: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/CMSC426/Convolution.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_correlation_analysis